# how to fix the problem in unity that when pressing pause all the ui buttons will disable and when i press resume they will enable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

i have an problems when i pause the game its suppose to be an dark but some ui gameobjects still show like this here when i play the game first

[image]

and here when i press pause

[image]

so i want an help of what to do its okay if i have to write script or anything, thanks for anyone will help me.

i,ve tried to write script to make the gameobjects that has tag name with (Camera) i name them all Camera, so i,ve tried if i press pause they will set active false and if i press resume they will set active true but the problem here that it didnt work as i want see: here after i add script and pause it it work with pause

[image]

but, when i,ve pressed on resume its still set active false idont know what i did

[image]

heres the code:https://codeshare.io/DZ93pr

Comment: looks like some in game canvas is not correctly disabled and is probably overlapping the pause menu UI so you can't interact with it ...

Comment: ah, so thats why, ok i will try to fix this thanks for replay

Answer (score 0):

The layers of ui in unity is based on the order in the hierarchy. If you want your pause menu to be rendered above the normal ui, just drag you pause menu ui objects below the other ones in the hierarchy.